# eliminar jquery

Tags: angular, typescript

Como consigo o mesmo efeito em typescript/angular sem utilizar jquery.

```
$('#divPublicar').mouseenter(function() {
  this.isOnDiv = true;
});

$('#divPublicar').mouseleave(function() {
  this.isOnDiv = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma diretiva, segue exemplo pra deixar o elemento mais escuro quando o mouse estiver sobre ele:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[apDarkenOnHover]'
})
export class DarkenOnHoverDirective { 

    @Input() brightness = '70%';

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private render: Renderer
    ) {}

    @HostListener('mouseover')
    darkenOn() {
        // aqui você vai colocar o comportamento que você desejar quando mouse estiver em cima do elemento
        this.render.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'filter', `brightness(${this.brightness})`);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')
    darkenOff() {
        // aqui você vai colocar o comportamento que desejar quando o mouse deixar o elemento
        this.render.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'filter', 'brightness(100%)');
    }
}
```

Para adicionar a diretiva no elemento basta adicionar o nome dado à diretiva como se fosse um atributo da tag:

```
 <div apDarkenOnHover></div>
```

Lembrando que é uma boa prática o uso de diretivas para aprimoramento de elementos, segue links de apoio:
[Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#directives)
[O que são diretivas e como usar](https://www.portalgsti.com.br/2017/08/o-que-sao-diretivas-no-angularjs-e-como-usar.html)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar um exemplo de como pode ser feito, sendo que existem várias formas de se fazer isto e mostrarei talvez a mais fácil, agora aconselho dar uma estudada antes no **Angular** e ver como ele funciona, como ele acessa e manipula o `DOM`, pq isto é o básico, se não está conseguindo fazer esta funcionalidade com Typescript é pq ainda não assimilou os conceitos que precisa para mexer com o framework:

**HTML**

```
<div (mouseenter)="Enter()" (mouseleave)="Out()"></div>
```

**TS**

```
public isOnDiv: boolean;

Enter() {
   this.isOnDiv = true;
   console.log('ENTROU NA DIV');
}

Out() {
   this.isOnDiv = false;
   console.log('SAIU DA DIV');
}
```

> Pode ver o exemplo funcionado [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mouses)